# jQuery to do list done button not removing item

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am creating a simple to do list using jQuery and local storage. I am also trying to add a button for each li I add to clear the item from the list. My list does not stick upon refresh and I can't figure out how to load the button, does the button need to happen on the HTML side?

The adding to the list functions work great its just the storage to local storage that I seem to be missing something.

I created a jsfiddle for this code and the local storage seems to work fine but it will not work on my xampp. Also I can get the done button to appear but it won't removeItem.

https://jsfiddle.net/blen6035/287pc153/7/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Task List</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="tasks.js"></script>    
</head>

<body>
 <aside>
  <h2>Add a task</h2>
  <label for="task">Task:</label>
  <input type="text" id="task" name="task"><br>
  <label>&nbsp;</label>
  <input type="button" id="add" name="add" value="Add Task"> 
 </aside>
 <main>
  <h1>Task list</h1>
  <ul id="listOfTasks"></ul>
 </main>
 <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

```
"use strict"

$(document).ready(function() {

    let listOfTasks = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem("tasks"));
    if( listOfTasks == undefined ){
        listOfTasks = [];
    }
    for( let i = 0; i < listOfTasks.length; i++){
        let li = $('<li> <a href="#" id="done">Done</a> 
        </li>').text(listOfTasks[i]);
        $('#listOfTasks').append(li);       
    }

    $('#add').click(function(){
        let task = $('#task').val();

        listOfTasks.push(task);
        localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(listOfTasks) 
  );

    let li = $('<li></li>').text(task);
    $('#listOfTasks').append('<li>'+ task +'<input type="submit" 
   class="done" value= "Done">' + '</li>');
    $('#task').val(' ').focus();
    });

$('.done').on('click', '.delete',function(){
$(this).parent().remove();
 });
/*$('#done').click(function(){
    localStorage.removeItem;
    $('#listOfTasks').html('');
});*/

}); // end ready
```

Comment: can you also share your HTML please?

Comment: your code would make multiple `<a>` with `id="done"` - ID's must be unique in valid HTML

Comment: Some basics: https://www.w3schools.com/hTML/html_id.asp

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do ?

Note that I had to polyfill local storage to make this work in a snippet, replace `fakeLocalStorage` by `localStorage`

```js
const listOfTasksElement = $('#listOfTasks')
const taskInputElement = $('#task')
const listOfTasks = JSON.parse(fakeLocalStorage.getItem('tasks')) || []

const updateTasks = () => fakeLocalStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(listOfTasks))

const addTask = task => {
  const taskElement = $('<li></li>').text(task)
  const doneElement = $('<span>Done</span>').click(() => {
    const index = listOfTasksElement.find('li').index(taskElement)
    taskElement.remove()
    listOfTasks.splice(index, 1)
    updateTasks()
  })
  
  taskElement.append(doneElement)
  listOfTasksElement.append(taskElement)
  listOfTasks.push(task)
  updateTasks()
}

listOfTasks.forEach(addTask)

$('#add').click(() => {
  addTask(taskInputElement.val())
  taskInputElement.val('').focus()
})
```

```html
<ul id="listOfTasks"></ul>
<input id="task"><button id="add">Add</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  // local storage doesn't work in stack overflow snippets,
  // this is just a poor in-memory implementation
  const fakeLocalStorage = {
      _data: {},
      setItem(k, v) { return this._data[k] = v },
      getItem(k) { return this._data.hasOwnProperty(k) ? this._data[k] : null }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: The end result is the same but the method seems different than what I am going for. I created a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/blen6035/287pc153/7/ that the local storage is working on so I am not sure why it is not working on my xampp. I can also get the done button to appear but it doesn't actually removeItem and disappears when a new item is added.